# Issue with ASP.NET MVC Dropdown Editor Templates for Nullable Enums

Tags: asp.net-mvc, scaffolding

How can I treat a **Nullable** just like I do with **Enum** within the String.cshtml file?

---

**Background:**
I have successfully implemented a custom Editor Template for my enums (implementing the String.cshtml within the Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/String.cshtml.

I understood that it works as a fallback type for Enums, so whenever you have

```
Html.EditorFor(m => m.PropertyOfTypeEnum)
```

It creates my correcly a dropdown in which I can select the options.

**Problem:** the issue arises when my *PropertyOfTypeEnum* is a **Nullable<>**.
I don't understand exactly why, it does not fall back into the **String.cshtml** and therefore I can't treat it to render my dropdown list.

**Further Info:** I have double checked to see and it's actually NOT hitting my breakpoint at my **String.cshtml**.

Does anyone have any idea of how to treat it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that it is not working because calling `ToString()` on a null object would fail, therefore it is not able to infer to use **String.cshtml** by looking at the data type (which is null Enum and not null string).

You can help your editor template along by specifying that it should be used:
Add `[UIHint("String")]` in your view model for the required enum property.

**Alternative solution:** 
I had to solve the same problem but used a different technique.  I added an additional extension method for `DropDownFor` that understand enums.  For example:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression) 
               where TProperty : struct
{
            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList = DropDownHelper.ToSelectListItems<TProperty>();
            return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, selectList);
}
```

Comment: brilliant! that worked very well. Didn't know you could define the template in the model, which fits it brilliantly. Thanks Philip!